# JSHint returning odd errors

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following script that i created with some help from the people here on stacks for creating a calculator and updating the DOM correspondingly. I recently have changed my editor to one that has JSHint. I has given me some odds errors which I'm hoping someone could provide insight into.

The main one is "Don't make functions with in a loop" That is referring to the .addEventListener array push. Why is this a problem and why should I be doing it this way?

```
var currentFunction = [];

    function pushToArray(v){
      currentFunction.push(v);
      addtoScreen(v);

    }

    function addtoScreen(vTag){

      var screen = document.getElementById("screen");

      if(currentFunction.length == 1){
        var newCalc = document.createElement("p");    
        newCalc.className = "calc";

        var opInt = document.createElement("span");
        opInt.innerHTML = vTag;

        newCalc.appendChild(opInt);
        screen.appendChild(newCalc);
      }else if(vTag == "="){
        var opInt = document.createElement("span");
        opInt.innerHTML = vTag;

      }else{
        var opInt = document.createElement("span");
        opInt.innerHTML = vTag;

        newCalc = screen.lastChild;

        if(newCalc){
          newCalc.appendChild(opInt);
        }else{
         screen.appendChild(opInt);   
        }
      }
    }

    var numbers = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
      if(numbers.item(i).id != "equalButton"){
        numbers.item(i)
          .addEventListener("click", function(){pushToArray(this.value);});
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function will be constructed on every iteration if it is within the loop. Declare the function outside the loop and call it within the loop. 
Or you can add loopfunc : true tag for jshint ignore.

Comment: when i wrote it as 

'.addEventListener('click', pushToArray(this.value))'

it didn't work though. What would be the right way to write it then?